# Register Spring Boot Configuration class, with generics, programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-configuration

I have a configuration class that requires a generic configuration class defined like this in Spring Boot 3.2:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfig<T> {
  
   @Bean
   public MyThing<T> myThing() {
      new MyThing<T>();
   }

   @Bean
   public MyOtherThing<T> myThingOther() {
      new MyOtherThing<T>();
   }

}
```

Since `MyConfig` takes a generic type, `T`, I've tried registering the class like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class SomeConfiguration implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar {

    @Override
    public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        Class<?> type = Class.forName("org.something.SomeThing");

        Class<?> myConfig = GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(MyConfig.class, type);
        GenericBeanDefinition definition = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        definition.setBeanClass(myConfig);
        registry.registerBeanDefinition("myConfig", definition);
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, no beans of type `MyThing<T>` or `MyOtherThing<T>` are created (the methods in `MyConfig<T>` are never called). So my question is, how can I programmatically register the `MyConfig` class so that the beans are created?

Update:

You can see the actual code that I work with by doing:

1. Clone my github repo: `git clone git@github.com:johanhaleby/occurrent.git` (or `gh repo clone johanhaleby/occurrent`)
2. And then change branch to `experiment/spring-boot-annotation`: `git checkout experiment/spring-boot-annotation`
3. Run the `org.occurrent.example.domain.rps.decidermodel.web.TestBootstrap` class

The configuration that I want to load is `org.occurrent.springboot.mongo.blocking.OccurrentMongoAutoConfiguration`, and I try to load it from `org.occurrent.springboot.mongo.blocking.OccurrentMongoRegistrar` (which is triggered by annotation the `@EnableOccurrent` annotation used in `org.occurrent.example.domain.rps.decidermodel.web.Bootstrap` class).

Comment: Have you tried to annotate the beans with @Qualifier and wire them by name instead?

Comment: Not sure how this would help.

Comment: When you register a bean definition you do it by giving a name (a string, `myConfig` in your case ) and a resolved type. Something makes me think the type `MyConfig.class` resolves to something that you don't expect, and that is why your beans aren't being called. So what I meant in my first comment was: have you tried qualifying the bean class and use that same name in the registration (so that instead of letting Spring match the class, you make it match an exact key)?

Comment: I want to import the config by an annotation, i.e. I've created an annotation, `EnableMyStuff`, in which you specify the "generic type" (instead of doing `Class<?> type = Class.forName("org.something.SomeThing");` in the example above) that should be used as the generic parameter to MyConfig. So I'm not sure if qualifying would help, since I want the class to be imported from the annotation.

Comment: Can you share the code that you wrote? I am able to make it work with Qualified but I'm using the example above, having the real code would help to try to provide a real solution to your concrete problem.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I've added some instructions on how to see my actual code.